# Postgres query which it replys number which is last different value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to query which replys last different values row number from current row.
NUMBER takes only 2 value.

Table A is given

```
ROWNUM NUMBER
1      1        
2      1        
3      1        
4      1        
5     -1        
6     -1        
7      1        
8      1        
9     -1  
10     -1 
11     -1
```

EXPECTED result FROM Table A by some query.

```
ROWNUM NUMBER LASTDIFFERENT
1      1        5
2      1        4
3      1        3
4      1        2
5     -1        3
6     -1        2
7      1        3
8      1        2
9     -1  
10     -1 
11     -1
```

Comment: What is data missing from the expected output?  I don't follow the logic here.

Comment: thank you editing jorge!

Comment: I can not find any query which fulfill which I expect result.

Comment: oh I failed expected result.... let me revise.

Comment: Where does the `5` in the first line come from?

Comment: Hi Biegeleisen, 1st row is 1, so I want row number which appears -1 and nearest. 2nd,3rd, 4th row is 1 so nearest -1 is 5th row from 1st row. 6th row is -1 so next row is nearest row and different value, so I want 2 at here.

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name, 5 comes from 5th row. because its different number, -1.

Comment: @Takoyaki Your `Table A` is broken. Every row has to be distinct from other rows. If You need an order, You have to add special field for it.

Comment: hi Michas, I added rownum column.

Answer (score 0):

This might fall into the category of "just because you can doesn't mean you should."  I don't see any elegant solutions to your problem, but this is a working solution, at least for your sample data:

```
with switches as(
  select
    rownum, number,
    case
      when lag(number) over (order by rownum) = number then 0
      else 1
    end switch
  from TableA
),
groups as (
  select
    rownum, number, sum (switch) over (order by rownum) group_id
  from switches
)
select
  rownum, number, -- group_id,
  max (rownum) over (partition by group_id) - rownum + 2 as last_different
from groups
```

I ran this on your sample data and got these results:

```
rownum  number  last_different
1       1       5
2       1       4
3       1       3
4       1       2
5      -1       3
6      -1       2
7       1       3
8       1       2
9      -1       4
10     -1       3
11     -1       2
```